# Regex reverse lookbehind

Tags: regex-lookarounds

I am having some issues in understanding how to use lookbehind in regex.
I need to match all **between the first preceding occurrence** of ***myMethod*** and ***somethingelse***

Example
https://regex101.com/r/lF8yT0/4

```
public myMethod
do something

private myMethod
do somethingelse


(?s)(?<=(myMethod){1})(.*)somethingelse
```

Selects all from the top, while I only expect

```
private myMethod
do somethingelse
```

Comment: Why would you expect `foo bar` as the match for your regex.  Can you clarify your logic?  The Regex101 example you gave seems to show something different.

Comment: I enhanced the example.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a [**tempered greedy token**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970):

```
[^\r\n]*myMethod((?:(?!myMethod).)*?)somethingelse
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/deRkS9/1)

The first `[^\r\n]*` matches 0+ chars other than CR/LF (since you expect the start of the line in your match result) and `(?:(?!myMethod).)*?` matches any 0 chars (as few as possible) that do not start a `myMethod` substring.